# EasyPHP: transferring my data to a new install with files only (no database dumps)

Tags: easyphp

I reinstalled Windows (I had v8.1, now v10) but forgot to save my databases as dump files. I do have my old `EasyPHP` folder with everything in it though. So I installed a new `EasyPHP` but now I don't know how to transfer my databases from the old `EasyPHP` install to the new one.

I tried to copy the content of my old binaries/mysql/data/ to the new one, to no avail (database connection errors).

- Old EasyPHP: `EasyPHP DevServer 14.1 VC11`
- New EasyPHP: `EasyPHP DevServer 14.1 VC9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [some people have faced the same problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63065/trying-to-recover-import-transfer-database-from-mysql-data-dir) too. This is my solution:

I simply ignored the regular, proper install process. I just launched the main executable (EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11.exe), got a message asking me to update configuration file (sorry I don't remember what exactly), I clicked yes, and now I obtain the exact same state as before. No need to go through any install process.

I'll update this answer if I come across any unexpected problem down the line but it seems to work pretty well so far.